# Recover ext4 file

Tags: linux, ext4

How to recover recently deleted file from ex4 partition?

Mashine hosts Open SUSE 11.2 (kernel 2.6.31)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the tried-and-true testdisk/photorec. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

It is on SystemRescueCD.

FIRST, though, umount that harddrive! the more writes you to do it (including simple timestamp updating, etc.), the less chance you have of recovering the file.

Answer (score 0):

undeleting with ext3 is easy, unfortunately undeleting under ext4 is pure horror (does it zero out journals?)

only chance: use testdisk -> photorec /dev/sdx (can restore content of files, but not the filenames!) under "File Ops" it is possible to enable only specific filetypes (xlsx & docx = zip)

[how to get deleted files back from ext4](https://dwaves.de/2017/07/06/gnu-linux-recover-deleted-files-ntfs-undelete-ext3-vs-ext4-rescue-accidentally-deleted-data-files-overwritten-partition-table-foremost-gpart/)

good luck!

making the case for ZFS snapshots?